# Elantra will not start

Tags: starting, hyundai, elantra

My 2013 Hyundai Elantra will not start.  Battery tested good at Napa yesterday.  The lights and dash come on, car says it's in park (I've tried N as well)  Everything is normal with the starting except when the engine is supposed to fire up.  It just seems like there's no gas getting to it.  Any thoughts?  The car is still under the extended warranty so I'm hoping they will tow and fix whatever it is for free.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the engine turn over, as in, when you turn the key to the start position, does the engine make noise? OR do you just hear a click and nothing? Or just *nothing*?

Comment: The starter makes is normal noises and then the engine doesn't make a sound.

Comment: I have the same problem!!!! It's happened to me 3 times in 1 week, where all of the sudden the car won't start, I have to try over 10 times for it to start. It's so strange.

Comment: @Hizelks, what was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic sequence for diagnosing starting problems

1) Does the engine turn over normally ? if it doesn't turn over at all or only does so sluggishly this immediately suggests a problem with the battery or starter motor. If you can jump start it ok that implies a battery problem, either a dead or damaged battery or an electrical fault which is draining it.

2) If the engine turns over but doesn't start this implies a fuel, compression or spark problem. with a modern car this opens up a huge number of potential causes but it is worth checking visually for any loose cables or evidence of a fuel leak.

3) One other possibility is if the engine immobiliser has kicked in this can happen for a number of reasons eg a faulty key transponder or if the alarm has been triggered and not properly reset. It may be worth checking your owners manual to see of there is a reset procedure. The same can also apply if the fuel pump cutoff has been  triggered by an impact.

Unless you can find an obvious problem and the car is under warranty just make a warranty claim. There is a very good chance that this is an ECU or sensor issue.

Comment: Don't most immobilizers cause it to not even turn the engine over when it's kicked in?

Comment: It depends, some may disable the fuel pump (as most vehicles have a fuel pump cutoff anyway) or cut the spark in any case this could still apply in case (1)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to test for is the fuel pump. Turn the key to 'On', but don't start the car. Do you hear a hum coming from the back of the car? Hum means fuel pump is working. No hum, you found part of the problem, you should check the fuel pump fuse next.

If the fuel pump is humming for a few seconds, the trouble like resides in the engine not getting fuel, spark or compression. To add to Chris Johns' answer:

1. **Check for spark:** most cars don't have ignition cables anymore, which makes this a little bit risky. Pull the plugs out of the engine and try to start. Have somebody looking at the spark plugs, make sure they spark. In the olden days, you could just attach a timing light to each ignition cable.
2. **Check for compression:** a compression tester is an inexpensive tool ($15) that is useful to have for mystery problems like this. Perform a compression test on all your cylinders, make sure compression is even and is close to specs.
3. **Check for fuel delivery:** this one is a bit harder. You can test the fuel pressure in the fuel line first with a fuel pressure gauge. If that checks out, you can check individual injectors by pulling the spark plugs out one at a time, trying to start and having someone with their face above the open cylinder smelling for gasoline.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I tried starting it again this morning.  I could hear the fuel pump underneath the back seat.  With my limited car knowledge I think it's just time to call the tow truck in.

Comment: So someone on another site mentioned pulling out the usb cable connected to my ipod.  No joke the car fired right up after that. WTF! The power of Apple took down my Elantra

Comment: Some cars the USB is only on when the key is turned to on, so when you are trying to start, your iPod is getting some power as well. I've never heard it stop a car from starting though, but yeah, keep all your electricals off when trying to start.